# Python - for loop with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

My function works, but I want to be able to take a user input for how many passwords, then loop through the function, but it's only going through it once.
I've also tried a 'while True; loop, but no joy neither.

```
import string
import random

usernumber = (input('\nHow many passwords: '))
amount = usernumber

def genpass():
    
    length = int(input('\nEnter the length of the password: '))

    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    num = string.digits
    symbols = string.punctuation

    all = lower + upper + num + symbols
    temp = random.sample(all,length)

    password = "".join(temp)
    print(password)

for i in amount:
    genpass()
```

Comment: covert your `input` to an `int` with `int(usernumber)`, and use `for i in range(amount)`

Answer (score 1):

You actually need `usernumber = int(input('\nHow many passwords: '))` and

```
for i in range(amount):
    genpass()
```

When you don't convert a string to integer and use it in a for loop, it will iterate over the characters or the length of the string, not the number. In your code, when you enter `1`, it gets converted to `'1'` as input returns a string. This value is assigned to `amount`.

This will actually iterate only once because there is only one character in the string.

```
for i in amount:
    genpass()
```

Comment: The 1 thing I didn't try was adding the 'range' as I didn't think would make sense but now I get it. Thank you!

Comment: @GoatMasterUK, range is a generator. If you do ```for i in amount```, it will raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `input` you get a string, meaning `amount` is also a string. When you iterate over that, `i` will be each character in the string: so inputting `4` will run the `genpass` loop once, with `i`=`4`.

To iterate a number of times you need to parse the input to a number and run that many times. For instance:

```py
amount = int(usernumber)
for i in range(amount):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with integers in inputs, you need to add int to the input :) and adding range to "for i in range amount"

That should do the trick, let me know if there is any errors :)

import string
import random

usernumber = int(input('\nHow many passwords: '))
amount = usernumber

def genpass():

```
length = int(input('\nEnter the length of the password: '))

lower = string.ascii_lowercase
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
num = string.digits
symbols = string.punctuation

all = lower + upper + num + symbols
temp = random.sample(all,length)

password = "".join(temp)
print(password)
```

for i in range amount:
genpass()

Answer (score 0):

### **You had made some mistakes while getting input in "usernumber" and forgot to add range command in last**

```
import string
import random

usernumber = int((input('\nHow many passwords: ')))
amount = usernumber
length = int(input('\nEnter the length of the password: '))
def genpass():
    
    

    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    num = string.digits
    symbols = string.punctuation

    all = lower + upper + num + symbols
    temp = random.sample(all,length)

    password = "".join(temp)
    print(password)

for i in range(amount):
    genpass()
```

**I also moved the "length of password" block out of the loop for some simplicity.**

Comment: Sujay answered it above, see my reply to his message, but moving the 'length' in out of the function was ideal too! Thank you!